# How to get child record with without parent?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to query all parent record based on the total number of child record and group by Parent but the aggregate query is not returning the child record without parent.

```
SELECT Parent__c, COUNT(Id)
FROM Child__c
GROUP BY Parent__c
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are any children without parents, you'll get a row back that has a null value for the Parent__c field. Apparently you don't have any matching records. Here's an example from my developer org:

[image: Children with/without parents]

Comment: So how can I get those Parent__c record which does not have child__c record? Actually I am trying to display all the parent based on no of child__c in descending order including parent with child as 0

Comment: The most efficient way to do this would be to use two queries. Put all parents in a map, then use a query like this (including `ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC`), then build a final result list.